# Damage to player when activating Flying ability after 'Declare Blockers' step

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I attack with a [Leaping Master](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Leaping%20Master) and my opponent blocks it with an [Alpine Grizzly](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Alpine%20Grizzly) and I then activate the Leaping Master's Flying ability (i.e. at the end of the 'Declare Blockers' step), the Alpine Grizzly can, presumably, no longer block the (now flying) Leaping Master.

However, would Leaping Master deal damage to my opponent in this case or does rule **509.1h** prevent this?

> **509.1h** An attacking creature with one or more creatures declared as blockers for it becomes a blocked creature; one with no creatures declared as blockers for it becomes an unblocked creature. This remains unchanged until the creature is removed from combat, an effect says that it becomes blocked or unblocked, or the combat phase ends, whichever comes first. A creature remains blocked even if all the creatures blocking it are removed from combat.

My feeling is that Leaping Master's damage *is* assigned to the player as the Alpine Grizzly is not "removed from combat"?

Comment: +1 for a well titled (in my opinion) question. By the way, you can use `[mtg:Card Name]` to tag cards. There are a few [caveats](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/794/6692), but it works most of the time.

Comment: Thank you; I tried to put something meaningful but not too long-winded :)  Thanks for the [mtg:] tip!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flying only creates a restriction on blocking when blockers are declared, once the blocker is declared giving the attacker flying will have no effect.

From the Rulings on Leaping Master

> 9/20/2014  Activating Leaping Master’s ability after it’s been blocked won’t change or undo the block.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! (note to self: read content of linked pages *fully* to avoid looking dumb!)

Comment: It's also in the rules: "509.1b. If an attacking creature gains or loses an evasion ability after a legal block has been declared, it doesn't affect that block." So this is not something unique to Leaping Master. (i.e. the ruling is just a clarification)

Comment: Thank-you for that David; it's always useful to have the actual rule to refer to.